# Qt Abstract Model - flags() function never called

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I'm currently working on a **Qt Quick application** in which there is a **[TableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html)** showing data from a **backend model** written in C++ (it is a custom model derived from **[QAbstractListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html)**).

I want to have to possibility to set which rows can be selected by the user, so I thought to extend the custom model by overriding the function:

```
Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
```

The change I made has no effect on the application and by debugging I noticed that the *[flags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#flags)* function is **never called** by anyone (tried both using a breakpoint and printing on console).

I tried several things (even changing the base model from QAbstractListModel to QAbstractTableModel) but didn't figure out why it is not working.

At the end I tried to launch an **official example** (**[Qt Quick TableView examples - Conway’s Game of Life](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qtquick-tableview-gameoflife-example.html)**) provided by **Qt Creator** but it has the same behavior (flags function overridden but never called).

How is that function supposed to work?

I'm using Qt Creator 4.10 with Qt 5.13.1 MSVC2015 (64 bit).

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, the QML views do not use the flags() function, unlike the Qt Widgets delegates (QStyledItemDelegate, QItemDelegate) that do use them.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks, that would explain the behavior I'm observing! How did you know? I didn't find anything in the documentation, do you have any reference or hint about where to start looking?